# Sort AtomicLongMap by value

Tags: java, sorting, dictionary, guava

I´m using a guava AtomicLongMap to count the number of phrases in a document.

```
AtomicLongMap frequentPhrases = AtomicLongMap.create();
frequentPhrases.getAndIncrement(phrase.trim());
```

Everything works like a charm, but I cannot find a way to sort that Map by the number of occurrences.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? Do you mean you want to iterate the map in an ascending/descending order of the values?

Comment: yes, after add all the entries I want iterate descending

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could save the entries to a `List`, and then sort it by the entry's value, in reverse order:

```
List<Map.Entry<Object, Long>> sorted = 
    new ArrayList<>(frequentPhrases.asMap().entrySet());
Collections.sort(sorted, Collections.reverseOrder(Map.Entry.comparingByValue()));

for (Map.Entry<Object, Long> entry : sorted) {
    System.out.println(entry); // Or something more useful
}
```

Comment: Not bad. I see one issue though: Race conditions. If right after the `Collections.sort` call some other thread was modifying `frequentPhrases`, the output would be wrong.

Comment: @Brian yup - the minute you take the entries out of a thread safe object and manipulate them yourself, you're losing all promises of atomicity. This entire block should probably be protected somehow.

Comment: I agree. Maybe giving up some of the solution's elegance by copying the entry values instead of referencing the originals would help. This way one would have a snapshot in time. Could be useful.